# What is a single word for feeling like you could have done more?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to find a word that describes the feeling like you could have done more or something could have been better if you put in more work but did the best you could at the time.

Comment: 'Underachievement' is (if true) what has 'happened', but you would have to use a phrase ('feeling/sense of 'underachievement') for the emotion. 'Anxiety' is, of course, too broad.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for **hindsight**

Comment: A sense of _inadequacy_.

Comment: @KannE One can always do more. With experience, with hindsight, with increased motivation. But tomorrow is another day and the dawn will bring fresh opportunities :)

Comment: Perhaps wishing you were more _proactive_?

Answer (score 0):

Frustrated.

> ### frustrate
>
> verb (used with object), frustrated, frustrating.
> 1.
> to make (plans, efforts, etc.) worthless or of no avail; defeat; nullify:
> *The student's indifference frustrated the teacher's efforts to help him.*
> 2.
> to disappoint or thwart (a person):
> *a talented woman whom life had frustrated.*

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/frustrate))

Comment: I have added in a dictionary definition and a link to add to your answer. Next time make sure to cite evidence that could be used to add to you answer.

Comment: Seriously? I presume the OP could look up a dictionary definition without me having to do it for them! (Just joined this forum - so far finding it a friendly little place - not.)

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, I didn’t mean to be patronising. The forum requires answers to contain a certain amount of detail and usually with a single word request that means a definition. It’s just so that you can compare the answers without having to do extra research - that’s what the answerers have to do. The forum is a bit split between a few really high rep people who whizz around leaving copy and pasted comments and low rep people leaving decent if not detailed answers

Comment: Okay, thanks for the nice response to my snarky one. :)

Answer (score 0):

*I* [**regret**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regret) *I was unable to (or did not) do more at the time.*

> sorrow aroused by circumstances beyond one's control or power to repair